Change PIVOT data source Using VBA?
I have an excel file with sheet1 and pivottable4. The source data of pivottable4 is "path" "file" "sheet" and "range".
Im looking for a line of code that will update pivottable4 with "path" "file" "sheet" and "range".
I've tried various examples with no success. I can't seem to get the SourceData with a full path working.
...
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pvtcache As PivotCache
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim PivotSource As String
    Dim PivotName2 As String
    Dim PivotName4 As String
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook

    PivotName2 = "PivotTable2"
    PivotName4 = "PivotTable4"
    'Get Data Source File Path and File Name
    FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CY6 Excel (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    PivotSource = "'[" & FilePath & "]Data'!$A:$AN"

    MsgBox "Pivot FileName" & PivotSource, vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set PivotSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sandbox")
   'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
    Set pvtcache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PivotSource) 'Error 1004 application defined error

    ThisWorkbook.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache pvtcache 'Error 1004 application defined error
    PivotSheet.PivotTables(PivotName2).RefreshTable

    PivotSheet.PivotTables(PivotName4).RefreshTable
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

...

Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Added what I have so far. Keep in mind, I'm a newbie and 1st time at this.

The 2nd argument should be passed a Range object (when SourceType is either xlConsolidation or xlDatabase).
Microsoft documentation:

PivotCaches.Create method (Excel)

'*** Untesed Code ***
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pvtcache As PivotCache
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim PivotSource As String
    Dim PivotName2 As String
    Dim PivotName4 As String
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook

    PivotName2 = "PivotTable2"
    PivotName4 = "PivotTable4"
    'Get Data Source File Path and File Name
    FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CY6 Excel (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")

    ' *** Change Start
    Dim dataBook As Workbook, dataSht As Worksheet, pvtSource As Range
    dataBook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dataSht = dataBook.Worksheets("Data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If dataSht is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't found sheet named [Data]"
        dataBook.Close False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set pvtSource = dataSht.Range("A:AN")
    ' PivotSource = "'[" & FilePath & "]Data'!$A:$AN"

    ' MsgBox "Pivot FileName" & PivotSource, vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set PivotSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sandbox")
   'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
    Set pvtcache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pvtSource) ' the 2nd argument should be a Range object
    ' *** Change End

    ThisWorkbook.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache pvtcache 'Error 1004 application defined error
    PivotSheet.PivotTables(PivotName2).RefreshTable

    PivotSheet.PivotTables(PivotName4).RefreshTable
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

